# Custom formatter

Tags: drupal

I need to create a new custom formatter(using the module custom formatter) to replace some template code. So, for some fields, When I add a new custom formatter(field type: text) I need to print the title and the body. I tried to use $node->title but it doesn't work...
How can I do this? Probably using elements? And if yes...how?
Thanks in advance,
Regards,
Michele

Answer (score 0):

Field formatters relate to the field that they are used for, it it's impossible to answer your question without know what field you are using (and it's contents).

To debug this, you could use the devel module and a bit of code. If you in your formatter write.

```
dpm(get_defined_vars());
```

this will give you a pretty printed list of all variables you have available. That should help you inspect and figure out how you get to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Custom formatters get's passed $element, if you do a dpm of $element (dpm($element) - If you have the Devel module installed) you will see the entire array, and notive that the $node object is passed as $element['#node'].

So with that said, to get to the node title you would use $element['#node']->title.

Please also not that it does say this on the help text of the custom formatters UI.